# How to Show $\log n = O(\sqrt{n})$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I am trying to solve this issue but I do not know how to handle the division by $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Prove the following using limits and L’Hôpital’s Rule: That $\log n$ is
$O(\sqrt{n})$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log n}{10^{1/2 \log n}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I am trying to read this issue but I can't. Also, it doesn't seem like provability is the right tag.

Comment: I have formatted your question using $\LaTeX$. Please make sure I haven't changed your intended meaning, and also consider learning some basic commands to help render your questions on this site.

Comment: In fact, $\,\log n=\cal O(n^\epsilon)\,$ , for any $\,\epsilon >0\,$

Comment: Actually $\log x < \sqrt x$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Let $a>0$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^a}=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using L'Hospital's rule:

$\log_{10} n = \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(10)}$, and let's call $k = 1/\ln(10)$. Then, derivative of the top is $k/n$ and of the bottom is $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. By L'Hospital's Rule,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k/n}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2k\sqrt{n}}{n} = 0$,

so indeed $\log n = O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Your proof shows $\log n = o(\sqrt{n})$, which is actually stronger than $\log n = O(n)$.

Comment: Where did that $k$ come from?

Comment: @AustinMohr Agree, but the last statement was only for what was asked for in the question...

Comment: @PeterTamaroff $k$ is defined in the answer as $1/\ln(10)$, which shows up if you interpret $\log x = \log_{10} x$, as the author of the question had done (instead of $\log x = \ln x$)

Answer (score 6):

You need to prove that $\log x \le c \sqrt x$ for some $c>0$ and for $x$ sufficienty large.

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt x - \log x$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt x -2}{2x}\ge 0$ for $x\ge4$.

Since $f(4)=2-\log 4>0$, we have $f(x)\ge 0$ for $x\ge4$.